# Why do some functions appear more than once in the import table?

Tags: api, delphi, hook, delphi-xe2

I am working on a resource leak detection unit, written in Delphi XE2. I want to monitor the creation and deletion of handles (file handles, event handles, etc) and GDI objects (bitmaps, brushes, etc.). So, every time a handle or GDI object is created, I want to put it in a list and when it gets deleted, I remove it. This way I am able to detect leaks, or duplicate deletions. To accomplish this, I hook the statically linked api's by altering the Import Table. Api's that are delay loaded or obtained by GetProcAddress are hooked differently, but that's not important for my question.

So much for the background information, now lets move on to the question.

When I was writing the hooking algorithm for the statically linked functions, I had to look into the PE file format and specifically the Import Table. I noticed that some imported functions (in my case for example 'CloseHandle'), are imported twice! I alos found that the some modules appear more than once. For example, the module 'kernel32.dll' occurred 6 times it the application I was working on.

*My question is, why do some functions appear more than once in the import table. And, why do some modules appear more than once in the import table?*

In my application I just replace all occurrences of a function to my function (the hook), but I was wondering what the reason is for these duplications. When I know the reason, I may need to change my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare an external import multiple times, in different units, it will appear in the import table multiple times. The compiler/linker does not merge them together.

If you declare an external import multiple times in the same unit, the compiler/linker does merge them into one.

Regarding `CloseHandle`, it is declared in the `Windows` unit. But in addition it is declared in `WindowsAPIs.inc` which is included by the `System` unit. So that's two declarations for starters. Clearly your program uses other units which re-declare `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The CloseHandle is found two times in the import table (like I said in the question, but maybe I was not clear enough about that), and you perfectly explained why. The import table has 6 arrays of kernel32.dll functions. Is it possible that I get an array of imported functions for every unit that declares kernel32.dll functions?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what seems to happen